# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$ for a homogeneous equation in $x,y$?

Tags: derivatives, curves

A problem book I use mentions the following:

> ...since the curve $32x^3y^2=(x+y)^5$ is homogeneous, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$

I have indeed verified the derivative. Is this a known theorem? I generalized it to $$cx^ay^b=(x+y)^{a+b},$$

but does there exist a more generalized form?

Comment: The implicit function theorem applied to $f(x,y)=c\,x^a\,y^b-(x+y)^{a+b}=0$

Comment: See as well [Euler Identity for homogeneous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function)

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici! Did you mean the implicit function differentiation? If yes, I did try applying it, but it results in [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+32x%5E3y%5E2%3D%28x%2By%29%5E5) mess of an expression to simplify!

Comment: @DatBoi Take that mess of an expression, and multiply by $xy/xy$ (or $(x+y)/(x+y)$), and then use the original equation to simplify the derivative.

Comment: @Teepeemm yes I have done that after Claude mentioned it in their answer :P

Comment: It's an idea with deeper implication, see page -108 [book](https://archive.org/details/differentialcal03edwagoog/page/n126/mode/1up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the rather surprizing relationship

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x}=\text{slope in point } \ (x,y)$$

is easy to understand on the curves of certain of these equations because these "curves" are in fact **union of straight lines**.

Let us take the case of the general equation you mention;

$$cx^{a}y^{b}=(x+y)^{a+b} \ \ \iff \ \ \left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^{a}\left(1+\frac{x}{y}\right)^{b}=c\tag{1}$$

Its curve, when non void, is plainly the union of lines passing through the origin (equations $y/x=t$), where $t$ is any real root of the following equation:

$$\left(1+t\right)^{a}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{b}=c \tag{2}$$

which may or may not have real roots.

Let us take the particular case $a=1, \ b=2, \ c=8$ (see figure) where equation (2), a third degree polynomial equation, has $3$ real  solutions, among them $t=1$. The resulting "curve" is made of the union of $3$ straight lines ; among them the line with equation $y/x=t=1$).

[image]

Comment: Interesting (as usual) and (+1). Cheers :-)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the curve is made up of the union of these straight lines"? Very interesting btw!

Comment: Let us take the case of equation $y^2-4x^2=c$ whose curve is a hyperbola when $c \ne 0$ and the **union of straight lines** $y=\pm 2x$ when $c=0$ ("the hyperbola reduced to its asymptotes")

Comment: I see what you mean! Great insight :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

For the general problem
$$f(x,y)=c\,x^a\,y^b-(x+y)^{a+b}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=a c x^{a-1} y^b-(a+b) (x+y)^{a+b-1}$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=b c x^a y^{b-1}-(a+b) (x+y)^{a+b-1}$$

Now, write
$$(x+y)^{a+b-1}=\frac 1 {x+y}(x+y)^{a+b}=\frac{c\,x^a\,y^b }{x+y}$$ Replace and simplify : the result is in three characters.

This is a direct application of Euler's identity for an homogeneous function as @Jean Marie already commented.

Comment: Hi, Claude. See the answer below.